# how to slice dates from a dataframe using standard input function?

Tags: python, pandas, stdin

I saw the documentation in the [Indexing and selecting data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.10.0/indexing.html) which involves hardcore scripting method to slice a range of data from a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('d1.csv')

df['time']=pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='ns')

df = df.drop('name', 1)

df['Time'] = df['time'].dt.time

df['date'] = df['time'].dt.date
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df = df.set_index(['date'])

df= df.loc['2018-07-04':'2018-07-05']
```

But I need to select a range of data from standard input function, How it can be done:

Rather than using `df= df.loc['2018-07-04':'2018-07-05']`say in the form at the console it will be asked to `Enter the start date :` and `Enter the stop date :` and by doing so I will get the data of the selected date ranges only.

I actually tried it doing as:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('d1.csv')

df['time']=pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='ns')

df = df.drop('name', 1)

df['Time'] = df['time'].dt.time

df['date'] = df['time'].dt.date
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df = df.set_index(['date'])
Starting_Date = input(" Please Enter the Starting_Date : ")
Ending_Date = input(" Please Enter the Ending_Date : ")

data = df[Starting_Date:Ending_Date]
```

But this doesn't work...kindly have a look upon it.

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Dawid_Sielski I have updated my question, Kindly have a look :)

Comment: @roganjosh I have updated the codes that I had worked, Now question is fully complete, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this. The date is in format `year-month-day` for example '2018-08-16'.

```
from datetime import datetime

a = input('Starting_Date: ')
b = input('Ending_Date :')

starting_date = datetime.strptime(a, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
ending_date = datetime.strptime(b, "%Y-%m-%d").date()

df.loc[starting_date:ending_date]
```

Hope that works for you :)

Comment: It gives a `TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be string, not int`

Comment: It is weird. Please try my code online in this link: https://repl.it/@dawidsielski/dateslice and say if it is producing any error.

Comment: Its working online. But not on my system IDLE... is it because I m using Python 2.7 ? @Dawid_Sielski

Comment: I am using python 3.6.2 and this might be the issue but to be sure I have to read the documentation for this function under python 2.7.

Comment: Please share the documentation link.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html -> doc link for python 2

Comment: And the issue probably is with input function. Please change `input` to `raw_input`.

Comment: Thanks :) @Dawid_Sielski

Comment: No problem :) Also if my answer helped you please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.